# Sequential promises in a Zapier trigger

Tags: javascript, promise, zapier

I have a Zapier trigger (app) that is retrieving data from a web service. The web service returns the data in blocks of 500 items, each item contains a UNIX timestamp and a web service parameter ('since') specifies the start time for the block of data that you want to retrieve.

In order for this to work I need to retrieve the data blocks sequentially, the data retrieved in the previous block allows me to find the 'since' value for the next web service call.

The code that I am currently using:

```
const fetchItems = (z, bundle, since) => {

    return z.request({

        url: URL_PATH + ':' + URL_PORT + '/v1/items',
        params: {
            since: since
        }

    }).then(( response) => {

        if (response.status === 401) {
            throw new Error('The authentication has expired.');
        } else if (response.status !== 200){
            throw new Error('Status ' + response.status + ' returned.');
        }

        return response.json;
    });
};

const processItems = (z, bundle) => {

    var jsonAll = [];
    var since = 0;
    var jsonLength = ITEM_BLOCK_SIZE;

    return (function loop(i) {

        if (jsonLength === ITEM_BLOCK_SIZE) {

            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

                fetchTransactions(z, bundle, since).then((json) => {

                    since = json[json.length - 1].modified;
                    jsonLength = json.length;

                    for (j = 0; j < json.length; j++) {

                        jsonAll.push( json[j]);
                    }

                    resolve();
                });

            }).then(loop.bind(null, jsonLength));

        } else {

            return jsonAll;
        }

    })(0);
}

module.exports = {
    ...
    operation: {
        ...
        perform: processItems,
        ...
    }
};
```

The issue that I have is that when I run this code Zapier return the following error: Results must be an array, got: undefined, ()

The fetchItems() function is working correctly, it is return the data blocks for the specified 'since' value.

I have limited experience working with promises so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `fetchTransactions` is not defined. should it be `...Items`?

Comment: And where do you get the error? You have no error handlers (.`catch(err) => {}) to catch those errors.

Comment: Oh, I start seeing problems with your code. This error you get is outside of this function. It comes from the code calling `processItems` (or `perform` as it is exposed as). The problem is that you are not returning a promise to wait for, and you also don't queue the actions creating these promises in any way.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Yes it should be fetchItems, my fault, sorry. Are you able to give me any examples of the changes that I need to make, my knowledge of promises is limited, this code is from examples that I found on the internet.

Comment: Added an answer 2 minutes before your comment ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Took me a while to untangle the intent of the `processItems`, but after a while I got the hang of the logic. I really appreciated simple beauty of the IIFE `loop` logic, and so kept that in my version, but you mixed up some assumptions of how synchronous and asynchronous code works (which is probably caused by unfamiliarity with promises).

```
const processItems = (z, bundle) => {
  const jsonAll = [];
  let since = 0;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    (function loop() {
      console.log("inLoop");
      fetchTransactions(z, bundle, since)
        .then(json => {
          const jsonLength = json.length;
          since = json[json.length - 1].modified;

          jsonAll.push(...json);

          if (jsonLength === ITEM_BLOCK_SIZE) {
            loop(jsonLength);
          } else {
            resolve(jsonAll);
          }
        })
        .catch(reject);
    })();
  });
};

// Testdriver (proves it works)
let callCount = 0;
const ITEM_BLOCK_SIZE = 10;
function fetchTransactions() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    if (callCount === 5) return resolve([{ modified: 100 }]);
    const list = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < ITEM_BLOCK_SIZE; i++) list.push({ modified: 42 });
    callCount++;

    resolve(list);
  });
}


processItems({},{}).then(results =>
  console.log(
    "results are correct?",
    results.length === 5 * ITEM_BLOCK_SIZE + 1
  )
);
```

The function as a whole is a *async* method, while any `return` statement in your code will of course be *synchronous*. That's why it returns `undefined`; the returned values are returned long after the function body has executed!

That's where `Promise`s shine. You can return a `Promise` from your method, and then just wait for the promise to be completed later on. That was what was failing: you basically needed to return a Promise which would be `resolve`d inside of the `loop` function.

So I added that, removed what I believe was some unnecessary `Promise` creation, and moved some global state into local state.

Comment: Thanks very much. I have just tried running this and I am getting the following error:

Comment: Sorry, shouldn't have pressed return. /private/var/folders/vl/_d19gjdd4sldhbl0bj93_c3h0000gp/T/zapier-d33348fc/triggers/receipe.js:38
    return new Promise( resolve, reject) {

Comment: So, it appears to be objecting to the opening curly brace.

Comment: Yeah, I assumed it had errors, so no surprises :-) Hard to run code without supporting functions! But if you take a look at your own code you'll see I missed ` => `. Added that now.

Comment: I am sure there are other syntax errors in the code. Regard it more as pseudo-code and see if you can work it out.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that - assuming that was the case - but I got another error: /private/var/folders/vl/_d19gjdd4sldhbl0bj93_c3h0000gp/T/zapier-85c24d3f/triggers/receipe.js:38
    return new Promise( resolve, reject) => {
           ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token new

Comment: Sorry we crossed messages.

Comment: @SteveP I added a testdriver that now proves it works. I stubbed the fetchTransactions method and it does what it should.

Comment: Many thanks for you help, all appears to be working. I tried to upvote your post but I was not allowed as I am a newbie on StackOverflow.

Comment: @SteveP, yeah, you might need > 100 points, but maybe you can _accept_ the answer (tick the checkmark)?

Comment: That is what I tried to do but no luck unfortunately. You need 15 reputation - the action is recorded, just not shown.